# MongoDB Java search array size

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Using MongoDB Java driver, I would like to find all entries where an array field contains at least 2 entries. What I have tried:

```
myCollection.find(new Document("arrayFieldname.length", new Document("$gt", 1)));
```

Unfortunately this returns no entry.

Should the approach be different?

Many thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can the [$size operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/), but that doesn't work for ranges.

The best thing to do is to add a field to the document that tracks the array size, and query based on that. The bonus with that approach is that you could index on that field.

Comment: But how to query in Java?